# Retrieve response text in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have sent an array to AJAX to return the status if the query is executed.

```
if(mysqli_query($dbconfig,"INSERT INTO todo(description) values('$desc')")){
        $response['success']="true";
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

In client side script, I tried following code to show message according to the status.

```
if(response.status=="success"){
      alertify.success("New item has been added successfully");
}else if(response.status=="error"){
      alertify.error("Error while adding the item");
}
```

Even the query runs correctly it doesn't satisfy both the cases. In my console log, status shows success.

[image]

Comment: Is the object that you're printing what you get in the success handler??

Comment: @r1verside sorry I did't get what success handler is. I just did               console.log(response); where response is parameter for function.

Comment: As an AJAX petition is asynchronous, the success handler is the function that you pass to your petition code as to be executed when the server respondsyour petition. I guess that it is where you wrote the `console.log(response)`. If so, any of the two solutions I provided in my answer should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided you can do two things

```
if(response.status === 200){
    //handle success
} else {
    //handle error
}
```

Or if you like, you could try with:

```
var status = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
if(status.status === "success"){
    //handle success
}else{
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: I tried both methods you provided. It goes in else condition even status is success

Comment: It is no sense, if in the result action handler you had put console.log(response) and the result is what you've pasted in your question. It has to work. Are you trying with [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

Comment: @SureshPokharel in the second choice there was an error, I was comparing the object in responseText instead of its status property